# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lexpo/modules/updates/db/DatabaseHolder;

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am making an app using React native in expo in a managed workflow.

Using `expo build:android -t apk` The apk file is generated but when I try to run it, the app crashes.

Does it have to do something with Async Storage?
How can I fix it without ejecting my project?

Here is the summary-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lexpo/modules/updates/db/DatabaseHolder;
    at host.exp.exponent.m.a.<init>(NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:11)
    at host.exp.exponent.m.a.c(NativeModuleDepsProvider.java:2)
    at g.a.a.b.<init>(Exponent.java:7)
    at g.a.a.b.m(Exponent.java:2)
    at host.exp.exponent.e.onCreate(ExpoApplication.java:9)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5826)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "expo.modules.updates.db.DatabaseHolder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.shuxton.tinnitus-opg0acEG2oe2-DZwFQt76Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.shuxton.tinnitus-opg0acEG2oe2-DZwFQt76Q==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.shuxton.tinnitus-opg0acEG2oe2-DZwFQt76Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 15 more
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-sms": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.6.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "10.7.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: did you enable "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds" in the android section of your app.json?

Comment: @Edgar is that setting known to cause this error?

Comment: @nxmohamad yes in some circumstances

Comment: Did you fix the issue? What caused it?

Comment: is this 'enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds'  makes issue?